# PHP: create subarray based on similar value types

Tags: php, arrays, key

Hello to the community: in the following array, I'd like to gather all the hobbies of the same user under that user's name into a subarray I'd call hobbies.

My current solution is to compare whether the email value is the same for both arrays, and if so, then push the hobby into its own array.

The problem is that the loops seems right but does not produce the results I expect it and I can't see where lies the problem. I thank you all for your time.

```
    for($x = 0; $x <= count($majorArray); $x++) {
       if($majorArray[$x]['email'] == $majorArray[$x+1]['email'])
             array_push($hobbies, $majorArray[$x]['hobby']);
}
```

The array:

Array
(

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [fname] => Eli
        [lname] => Solo
        [hobby] => plants
        [id] => 1
        [email] => elis@elis.com
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [fname] => Eli
        [lname] => Solo
        [hobby] => hiking
        [id] => 1
        [email] => elis@elis.com
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you compare the email of the current contents with the email of the next.

This check does not check if the user is already present, it just checks the next user in the array. This will only work if the next user is also the current, not if there is something in between.

Also, this code will eventually give you an `undefined index` error, as it will try to fetch the data under the next key in the last iteration.

Also it's not clear where `$hobbies` is from, according to you explanation, you want to create a `hobbies` array, and append all data there.

You can try the following (untested):

```
<?php

$majorArray = [
    [
        'fname' => 'Eli',
        'lname' => 'Solo',
        'hobby' => 'plants',
        'id' => 1,
        'email' => 'elis@elis.com',
    ],
    [
        'fname' => 'Eli',
        'lname' => 'Solo',
        'hobby' => 'hiking',
        'id' => 1,
        'email' => 'elis@elis.com',
    ],
];

$output = [];

foreach ($majorArray as $userData) {
    // check if email already exists as key, you can also just use id for this
    if (!array_key_exists($userData['email'], $output)) {
        $newUserData = [
            'fname' => $userData['fname'],
            'lname' => $userData['lname'],
            'id' => $userData['id'],
            'email' => $userData['email'],
            'hobbies' => [], // create the hobbies array
        ];

        // add the newly created user data array to the output with email as key
        $output[$userData['email']] = $newUserData;
    }

    // append the hobby to the hobbies array
    $output[$userData['email']]['hobbies'][] = $userData['hobby'];
}

// array_values will reset the array keys if you need to
print_r(array_values($output));
```

Comment: Your understanding of PHP is superb! this is exactly it! Thank you : )

Answer (score 0):

Simply write a new array and use the ID as key

```
$betterArray = array();
foreach($majorArray as $data){
 $betterArray[$data['id']]['fname']     = $data['fname'];
 $betterArray[$data['id']]['lname']     = $data['lname'];
 $betterArray[$data['id']]['email']     = $data['email'];
 $betterArray[$data['id']]['hobbies'][] = $data['hobby'];
}
```

notice the [] in the last line in the loop to add a new element to the subarray each time it loops trough